# add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sum1'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
            print("  ")
    def have (self,a,b):
        a=int(input("Enter A : "))
        b=int(input("Enter b : "))
    
class B(A):  
       def add(self,sum1):
        sum1=A+B
        print("Sum is: ",sum1)
   

obj = B()
obj.add()
```

the errors came

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-714fd5e33719> in <module>
     13 
     14 obj = B()
---> 15 obj.add()

TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sum1'
```

Comment: Does the answer below help? If it did, you can put closure to your question by choosing to accept the answer. To accept the answer, you can click on a checkbox beside the answer. That'll tell viewers of your question that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a bit like so:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
            print("  ")

    def have (self):
        # tell code to use this class's a and b variabes
        self.a = int(input("Enter A : "))
        self.b = int(input("Enter b : "))
        
class B(A):  
       # don't include anything in add except self
       # because a and b are already in class A
       def add(self):
        # use self.a and self.b that were inherited from A
        sum1 = self.a + self.b
        print("Sum is: ",sum1)
   

obj = B() 

# call the have method first to ask for inputs
obj.have()

obj.add()
```

Now, when you call `obj.have()`, you will be asked what A and B should be. But note that you are using capital A and B only as display. You are storing data into lowercase a and b. In the code above, we are using the class's a and b variables by using `self.a` and `self.b`.

Once those variables are populated, then we call obj.add(), which adds those 2 variables.

Check out some interesting literature about classes here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3